# Cant able to handle undefined from the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Below is the explaination of the script

- Based on the onwardflights length i am looping up and while
  displaying it is showing undefined in the view page
- I tried by using **typeof** for handling undefined, but no use.
- When i **console.log** the car_name, there is no undefined error, only
  while displaying it is showing error. Can any one help with this and handle this !!!!

> var onwFlights=response.data.onwardflights;
>
> > ```
> > for (var f=0; f<onwFlights.length;f++){
> > var car_name =onwFlights[f].airline;
> > carrier_array.push(car_name);
> > console.log(car_name);
> > }
> > ```

Below is the UI code

```
<script id="car_name_template" type="text/html">
    <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="{{car_name}}" class="f_all"> <span class="ccr_lab">{{car_name}}</label>
                        </div>  
</script>
```

Comment: may be the problem is not in this code.can you show us the ui code also

Comment: pls check the Ui code

Comment: on which line you are receiving the error ?

Comment: {{car_name}} in this place it is printing as undefined